# GNU Parallel: Delay first jobs sent to remote servers

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a gnu parallel script that imports data (100,000 jobs distributed to 100 remote servers) into a central database. The first jobs are slamming the central db because they finish almost at the same time. The jobs after that eventually spread out and don't try to import all at the same time.

Is there a way to delay the execution of the first job per remote server? So the script can say "run process #1 to server1 now, run process #2 to server2 in 5 seconds, run process #3 to server3 in 10 seconds, run process #4 to server 4 in 20 seconds, ..., ...". After that first batch gets sent to each server, id like the rest of the processes to run asap.

Is there a param for this?

Answer (score 3):

`--delay` from version 20121222 and `--sshdelay` from version 20130122.

= Edit =

The --delay is measured from the start of the job, so if your jobs run for longer than the delay*jobslots (e.g. 100 servers * 5 sec in your example) then you will feel as if there is no delay after the first batch.

Compare:

```
time parallel -S 2/: --delay 1 'sleep {};hostname' ::: 2 2
```

To:

```
time parallel -S 2/: --delay 1 'sleep {};hostname' ::: 2 2 2
```

The first takes 3 seconds, the 2nd 4 secs.

There is no functionality for dealing with first batch only. What you can do is something like:

```
parallel 'if [ {#} -lt 100 ] ; then sleep {#} ; fi; do_stuff {}'
```

where 100 is the size of the first batch.

Comment: Doesn't that delay all jobs though, not just the first batch sent to the remote servers?